# Variable name is changed after adding optional chaining in typescript class property

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I have written one typescript file. What's happening when I am trying to invoke some function(i.e this.details.name.fullname()) and if fullname() function is not available then I get `TypeError: this.details.name.fullname is not a function` in catch block. Which gives the complete information. But when I add optional chaining (i.e. this.details.name?.fullname()) then I get error `TypeError: _a.fullname is not a function`. _a is not giving any information what is object or anything.

The code I have tried is below

dummy.ts -:

```js
type details = {
    name: {
        firstname: string;
        lastname?: any;
        fullname?: any
    }
}
class Test {
    private details: details;
    constructor(details: details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public async printName() {
        try {
            this.details.name?.fullname()
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }
}


const obj = new Test({ name: { firstname: 'ashish', lastname: 'butola' } })

async function xyz() {
    await obj.printName()
}

xyz()
```

tsconfig.json -:

```js
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
      "module": "commonjs",
      "target": "es2015",
      "rootDir": "./src",
      "outDir": "./build",
      "inlineSourceMap": false,
      "strict": true,
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      "noImplicitThis": false,
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": [
        "dom",
        "es2017"
      ]
    },
    "include": [
      "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules",
      "build",
      ".vscode"
    ]
  }
```

I want the exact message i.e(TypeError: this.details.name.fullname is not a function) but at the same time I want to add optional chaining so it doesn't break because name can be undefined sometime. I think I am missing some property in tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Your configuration is targeting ES2015, which does not support optional chaining. Thus the Typescript compiler has to translate that into plain (old) JavaScript to implement the feature. If `name` is not `undefined` or `null`, but `fullname` is, you'll get that error.

Comment: I updated to latest es2017 still getting same error `TypeError: _a.fullname is not a function`. I want that full path `TypeError: this.details.name.fullname is not a function`

Comment: Optional chaining was introduced with ES2020. You can write your own code to test the value and throw whatever exception you want.

Comment: Yes. I updated to es2020. Now getting the correct Error with complete information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code optionally gets the `name` property of the details object, and then calls the `fullname` function on that value, unless the entire details object is undefined. You need to optionally call the function too, to account for the case where the object exists, but the function does not:

```
this.details.name?.fullname?.()
```